# React Native - How to use React Navigation with React Native Maps?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-navigation, react-native-maps

I have a scene that show some monuments in my city. When I press a marker (monument) it shows the name of the monument. What I want to do is, when I press that name I want to transit to a determined scene (with react-navigation). I wrapped the name of monument with a TouchableHighlight and on press I call the 'navigate' method. But it simply dont transit, it does nothing. Not even an error.

Here is my code:

```
render(){
const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    const { data }  = this.props.navigation.state.params;

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>

            <MapView
                style={styles.map}
                initialRegion={{
                    latitude: 39.604419,
                longitude: -8.411803,
                latitudeDelta: 0.0122,
                longitudeDelta: 0.0221,
                }}

            >
      {data.map(i => {
        if (i.category === "Museus"){
          return i.monuments.map((j, index) => (
                    <MapView.Marker
                        coordinate={{
                            latitude: j.latitude,
                            longitude: j.longitude,
                        }}

                        pinColor='#009688'
                        key={index}
                    >
              <MapView.Callout tooltip style={styles.callout}>
                <View style={styles.calloutContainer}>

                  <TouchableHighlight
                    onPress={() => navigate('MonumentoDetails')}
                    style={[styles.bubble, {backgroundColor:'#009688'}]}
                  >
                    <View>
                        <Text style={styles.name}>{j.name}</Text>
                    </View>
                  </TouchableHighlight>

                  <View style={[styles.arrow, {borderTopColor:'#009688'}]} />
                </View>
              </MapView.Callout>
            </MapView.Marker>
          ))
        }
      })}
            </MapView>
        </View>
    );
}
```

}

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: Sorry for the little information about my problem. I added a little more information. Hope it will help. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to test, if the TouchableHighlight is pressed function is being called. If not, try putting some console.log statement, to see if it is actually being pressed. Sometimes, it is not pressable due to outer layer pressable components